# How to use dropdown on a navbar with Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

- It's ASP.NET core application
- I'm using Bootstrap 5 installed with lib manager
  -Referenced the necessary bootstrap files according to the documentation

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link href="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js</script>

    <script src="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</environment>
```

- The navbar is in the `_Layout.cshtml` file, and within it is a list of nav-items of which I want one of them to be a dropdown

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
       data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Manage
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Administration"
               asp-action="ListUsers">Users</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Administration"
               asp-action="ListRoles">Roles</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

-The navlink shows on the browser but it is not clickable and does not show the dropdown items. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: May be jQuery link is not proper because clicking feature comes from jQuery. Check for console errors on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html code works fine. Be sure add the correct version bootstrap (**check the top line of the file** when open the `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css` and `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js` file).

Or you can use cdnjs reference. The whole HTML code looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - TestMVC</title>
    @* <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> *@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-6KY5s6UI5J7SVYuZB4S/CZMyPylqyyNZco376NM2Z8Sb8OxEdp02e1jkKk/wZxIEmjQ6DRCEBhni+gpr9c4tvA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">TestMVC</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">                   
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">                       
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                               data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Manage
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Administration"
                                       asp-action="ListUsers">Users</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Administration"
                                       asp-action="ListRoles">Roles</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2023 - TestMVC - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    @* <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> *@
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-ewfXo9Gq53e1q1+WDTjaHAGZ8UvCWq0eXONhwDuIoaH8xz2r96uoAYaQCm1oQhnBfRXrvJztNXFsTloJfgbL5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Result Display:

[image]

Comment: The issue was with creating an empty ASP.NET Core project and having to add everything from scratch, as I'm learning how to use the framework. The difference was referencing the jquery.js and bootstrap.js files toward the closing body tag. It worked, that way, but I really don't know why.